# Using 2-legged OAuth with Gmail IMAP

Tags: oauth, google-oauth, gmail-imap

I am trying to use OAuth to do a 2 legged authorization to the Gmail IMAP server, as documented
in https://developers.google.com/gmail/oauth_protocol.  I am having trouble, getting "invalid credentials" in response to the AUTHENTICATE XOAUTH command.

Obviously there are many potential points of error in my code, but I believe I have the SHA1 generation, URL encoding, Base64 encoding, all done correctly. My specific question right now is regarding how to identify my application as being allowed to use 2LO.   This documentation
(https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth#GoogleAppsOAuth) says that third party software vendors must register their application with Google to use 2LO, and that domain administrators must grant access to those vendors.  However, I have experimented with a commercial application that does this, and I am not required at any point to grant access to it, just supply it with my domain's consumer key and secret.  It works fine. (Nevertheless, I have gone into the Google Apps console and checked "enable this consumer key" and "allow access to all APIs").

In the IMAP XOAUTH protocol, where would I tell it what my application is?  The only place I see would be the "XOauth_requestor_id" parameter.  Is that it?  What do I put there?  I have tried the email address and various other values that I get from the Google API control panel, but nothing works.

Any help or examples (of all the input data and resulting base64-encoded output) you can provide would be appreciated.